# Why must we use "to becoming" in this case

Tags: gerunds

> both shared an innate ability to listen to music and play along on a range of instruments, the lack of any formal training meant this rough and ready unschooled  musician ship  was never going to enable them to compete in the professional musical world where Progressive Rock, with its genesis (pun intended)in the 1960's and had gone on a winding journey through the 1970's until it had travelled so far up its own arse it was now only visible by means  of medical imaging.
> Virtuosity and a deep knowledge of music theory seemingly being the entry tariff **to becoming** a rock musician.

Why not "to become"?.I know the rule if "to" works as a preposition use gerund, but my problem is why  is " to" a preposition in this case?

Does "entry tariff to"always  work with a noun after, or is it an expression  being something to + gerund.

In fact I thought I understood the reason  but  I realized I did not so I am asking a second time this question

Comment: That is a dangling sentence, no SVP (subject, verb, predicate). You should post what comes before that. That is a strange use of the word tariff. Normally, the price of doing something.

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this?  It appears to be an incomplete sentence. If that is all there is, then it's actually incorrect.  Can you please edit your question and provide the entire sentence if there is one. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not attributing the source of the text is plagiarism.

Comment: @Mari-LouAl, that's not correct. To constitute plagiarism. the person in question would have to be trying to pass off the quoted work as their own. That's not what's going on here (although I'd agree that providing a quote without attribution is certainly annoying! :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[unknown antecedents followed by this dangling sentence]
Virtuosity and a deep knowledge of music theory seemingly being the entry tariff to becoming a rock musician.

OK, *to* here is a **preposition**: we say in English "entry tariff to a market".

Since ***to*** is a preposition and not part of a to-infinitive, the gerund noun *becoming* is used. As in: "The man to see is sitting over there."

Be aware that some verbs must be followed by the gerund but that is not the case here. Two of those are: look forward to and get around to.